# How to edit the aliases with which a program in Ubuntu is associated (and therefore will be returned in the search menu)

Tags: search, alias

Pardon for for not having the correct terminology yet.

When I press the Meta button, Ubuntu lets me search for programs. When I, e.g., search for 'sound' it shows me a list of settings, programs, etc.

One of the programs listed is "audacity". Therefore, do I understand correctly that the program 'audacity' has an alias 'sound'.

Is there a way to lookup which aliases a program has defined, and can I edit this?

Comment: I don't have an Ubuntu machine in front of me, but try to check the folder `/usr/share/applications` and find the file `.desktop` for audacity. Open it and you should find what I prefer calling "tag". If my guess is right, you can copy the `.desktop` file to `/home/<your_username>/.local/share/applications` and edit this copy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keywords (aliases, tags) are in the application's .desktop file.

For example, Audacity's is `/usr/share/applications/audacity.desktop`

And the specific line within that file is: `Keywords=audio;sound;alsa;jack;editor;`

It is possible for you to edit the file (it's an ordinary text file) using `sudo` (it's owned by root). However, the next update of the package will overwrite your edits.

It is also possible for you to keep a custom .desktop file in your `/home/<your_username>/.local/share/applications` directory. However, this won't be automatically retained if you reinstall Ubuntu or migrate to a different system. It's up to the user to manage, maintain, and backup/restore custom files.

If there is a good keyword missing, please file a bug report and/or contribute a patch to the Debian packagers. Ubuntu improvements depend upon community contributions like this.

Comment: `However, this won't be retained if you reinstall Ubuntu or migrate to a different system.`: it is up to the user to manage these files: the user can put the saved files back on a newly installed system.

Comment: @vanadium edited; thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that in the `/usr/share/applications/audacity.desktop` file, next to the keywords, the aliases are also defined by the `GenericName` line. Since this is 'sound editor' for Audacity, Audacity would still pop-up after deleting the 'sound' under the `keywords` line.